# Process Json using VUE

Tags: json, vue.js

The following Json is recieved by the Vue Script, from a Php script which encodes an Array of Objects into JSON.

```
[{"title":"Clean Drinking Water","content":"Some     Content","link":"abd.html","img":"<img src="kkk.jpg" />"
},
{"title":"Clean AAAAAter Provided","content":"Lore Lipsum 
Test","link":"abc.html","img":"<img src="kkk.jpg" width="320" />"
}
]
```

[image: Screenshot of JSON received]

How do i access title, content, link and image data from this Json using Vue.  My Vue Code is

```
const url="lkl.php?get=json";
const vm=new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
    results:[]
  },
  mounted(){
    axios.get(url).then(response=>{
      this.results=response.data
    })
  }
});
```

I have tried {{ results.title }} {{  results[0].title }} but that doesn't seem to work. I am fairly new to Vue. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's not working because your JSON isn't valid. When you fixed that issue, it should be accessible with {{results[0].title}}